# Using realloc to shrink the string inside struct

Tags: c, string, memory-management, struct, realloc

I have a small question about using the realloc function. Assuming I have:

```
typedef struct
{
  char* location;
  int temp;
  int numberOfRec;
 }TEMP;
```

Then I declare a pointer to this struct in the main and allocate the memory:

```
int main()
{ 
  TEMP* data = xCalloc (1, sizeof(TEMP));  //wrapper function
  data->location = xCalloc (20, sizeof(char)); //wrapper function

}
```

Now if I reallocate the memory for data->location in another function. Do I need to return the address of TEMP* data?

```
int main()
{

 someFunction(data); // Use this function or...
 //data = someFunction(data);
 ...
}
void someFunction(TEMP* data)
{
  ...
  data->location = xRealloc (data->location, 10 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: no you dont have to return the adress of TEMP data as you passed it by  reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't. This is because `data` is a pointer to the structure. Whenever you access an element of the structure through `data` using the '->' operator, you are first de-referencing the pointer.

For example,

`data->location` ==> `(*data).location`

Also, when you do,

`data->location = xRealloc (data->location, 10 * sizeof(char));`

if the realloc fails, you would be leaking memory and possibly invoking undefined behaviour (if you don't include NULL pointer checks) because `data->location` has not been `free`d and it will be assigned to NULL since `realloc` returns NULL on failure.

I suggest you do the following instead.

```
void *temp = NULL;
temp = xRealloc (data->location, 10 * sizeof(char));
if(temp == NULL)
{
    // realloc failed.
    free(data->location);
    data->location = NULL;
}
else
{
    // Continue
    data->location = temp;
}
```

I compiled a [minimal example](http://ideone.com/30i4Z4) for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I am aware of the need to have checks for these functions. I have actually done them in wrapper.c so I don't need to recheck in main source file. Thanks anyway!